# Magento 2.2: How to add country and region drop-downs in a custom step form in one page checkout?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs, shipping-address, drop-downs

I need to add a **custom step in Magento which verifies the address of the customer via a third party API**, the fields are similar to the shipping address form, but I could not find out how the country and region drop-downs are added from the core files.

The fields in the shipping form are set from the `checkout_index_index.xml`, and displayed using the knockout for each loop, but I could not do the same.

Thanks 



**EDIT**
I have added the `country_id`, `region`, and `region_id` fields using layout xml, but it adds text box instead of the drop-down.

Answer (score 1):

To add the dropdowns in your custom module for checkout. You can use `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Checkout/DirectoryDataProcessor.php`as reference.

You need to create a plugin for the `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor::process` method. In your plugin, implement the after method adding the option data to the corresponding layout nodes at run-time.

> Create di.xml to declare the plugin

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd" >
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor">
        <plugin name='customDropdownPlugin' type='VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessorPlugin' sortOrder='999'/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Create VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessorPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Block\Checkout;


class DirectoryDataProcessorPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'])) {
            $jsLayout['components']['checkoutProvider']['dictionaries'] = [
                'custom_country_id' => $subject->getCountryOptions(),
                'custom_region_id' => $subject->getRegionOptions(),
            ];
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Here you need to replace `custom_cuntry_id` and `custom_region_id` with your fileds respectively.

Also check your attribute you have created must be of type select in `eav_attribute` table for customer address entity.

Comment: How do we use the added components in the layou xml file and display it in knockout template.

Comment: You just need to add your custom fields in checkout for that you can use follwoing link as reference. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html

Answer (score 0):

For me, seems reasonable to utilize existing checkout fields instead of the new step. Here are two guides that might help you:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_order.html
  http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_carrier.html

EDIT: one more guide for customer forms on checkout - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html

Comment: I have already used the guide from http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html to build the custom step, but what I need to achieve is only possible by adding the additional form similar to the shipping address,  as it is explicitly mentioned in the requirement document.